# How to apply line break in the comment for snowflake procedures?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Trying to input line break in the comment section, but it failed to display row by row.

Examples: When execute the query below, the output of the comment should be followed by the format below. However, the comment becomes "FunctionName:IfElse\nDescription: ..........."

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE APPROVALS_J_TEST("MYSTR" VARCHAR(16777216))

RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216)

LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT   
**comment** = FunctionName: IfElse
          
Description: ...........

EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS 

'if (MYSTR == ''0001'') 
{
    
return ''Success''
  
}
  
else if (MYSTR == ''0002'') 
{
    
return ''Success''
  
}
  
else {
    
return ''Failure''
  
}

';
```

Comment: please show some sample code and example wanted results

Comment: Hi @FelipeHoffa , the question has been updated, thanks.

Comment: Hi @mariomateas, the question has been updated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [CREATE PROCEDURE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-procedure) docs note comment is a single quote wrapped string.

> COMMENT = '<string_literal>'

so lets try one of those:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE APPROVALS_J_TEST("MYSTR" text)
RETURNS text
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT   
comment = 'FunctionName: IfElse
          
Description: ...........
'
EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS 
'
if (MYSTR == ''0001'') 
{   
  return ''Success'' 
} 
else if (MYSTR == ''0002'') 
{  
  return ''Success''
}
else {
  return ''Failure''
}
';
```

```
show procedures;
```

[image]

So it seems to work